# bcrypt-node 10.9 maybe node-gyp err?

Tags: bcrypt

I got this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'bcrypt'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:/slack-clone-server/models/user.js:2:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at loader (D:\slack-clone-server\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:144:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (D:\slack-clone-server\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:154:7)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Sequelize.import (D:\slack-clone-server\node_modules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js:393:62)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:/slack-clone-server/models/index.js:11:9)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at loader (D:\slack-clone-server\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:144:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (D:\slack-clone-server\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:154:7)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I tried bcryptjs and have the same problem. Any solutions?
Tried a lot staff from stackoverflow but still can't find the real solution.

Comment: it looks like you have not correctly installed a package

Comment: [Follow this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt). It seems that you haven't correctly installed you dependency  **:)**